# serializing and reading 2D sequence into/from TFRecords

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to serialize 2D vector (spectrogram of speech, varied in length) into a TFRecord.
is there any good example for this? i have tried some code [here](http://warmspringwinds.github.io/tensorflow/tf-slim/2016/12/21/tfrecords-guide/) and [here](http://www.wildml.com/2016/08/rnns-in-tensorflow-a-practical-guide-and-undocumented-features/), but it seem that it not suit my needs.
How do you serialize 2D (or any N-D array) varied in length sequence into TFRecords?

My current implementation (no errors, but i think it's not correct):

```
    # extract spectrogram from wav
    rate, wav = wavfile.read(wav_path)
    _, __, Sxx = spectrogram(wav, fs=rate, nperseg=254, noverlap=127)
    spectrogram_feat = np.moveaxis(Sxx, 0, -1)  # shift axis [freq, time] -> [time, freq]

    # make example
    ex = tf.train.SequenceExample()

    ex.context.feature['seq_length'].int64_list.value.append(spectrogram_feat.shape[0])
    ex.context.feature['n_feature'].int64_list.value.append(spectrogram_feat.shape[1])

    fl_spectogram = ex.feature_lists.feature_list['spectrogram']
    fl_label = ex.feature_lists.feature_list['label']

    for i in range(spectrogram_feat.shape[0]):
        # print(spectrogram_feat[i, :].reshape(1, -1))
        for f in spectrogram_feat[i, :]:
            fl_spectogram.feature.add().float_list.value.append(f)

    writer.write(ex.SerializeToString())
```